# jqgrid - delete row refreshes the page

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have the following code for the delete row:

**HTML**

```
<div class="Delete">Delete</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("div.Delete").live("click", function(){
   toDelete = $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
   $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('delGridRow',toDelete);
});
```

So, when I click on the "Delete" `div`:

- I get the confirmation dialog box but it shows up for only 2-3 seconds
- the page is then refreshed automatically

How can I make delete row work on the client side?

Comment: what d u mean by make delete row work

Comment: I want to delete a row in jqgrid. Currently, the row is not getting deleted on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should just use [reloadAfterSubmit: false](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties2) property of [delGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#delgridrow) method:

```js
$("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('delGridRow', toDelete, {reloadAfterSubmit: false});
```

If you in general prefer such behavior on the deleting of the rows by [delGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#delgridrow) method you can change the default parameters with

```js
$.extend($.jgrid.del, {reloadAfterSubmit: false});
```

If you include the code somewhere at the beginning all calls of `delGridRow` will use `reloadAfterSubmit: false` by default. By the way it's the standard setting which I mostly use.

Comment: I tried `reloadAfterSubmit:false` but the modal window still disappears after 2 seconds and the grid gets reloaded.

Comment: @SK11: In the case you should post more full code which you use.

Comment: Thank you but I figured it out. There was a problem with the url.

Comment: @SK11: In any way if you would use default setting `reloadAfterSubmit: true` the grid will be automatically reloaded after deleting of the row with `delGridRow`. So to prevent reloading you should use `reloadAfterSubmit: false` option.

Answer (score 0):

if your problem just in get confirm from client, use confirm in your code:

```
$("div.Delete").live("click", function(){
   if (confirm("Are You Sure?")) {
      toDelete = $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
      $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('delGridRow',toDelete);
   }
});
```